# Is there a way to use the Rolify gem in a multi-tenant setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, roles, rolify

I like the Rolify (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) API and would like to use it in my app but am having an issue finding anything in it's docs or tutorials that would allow me to define a role scoped to both a params[:account_id] && a resource instance. Has anyone used Rolify in such a way and could offer an advise on how to set this up?

Ideally this would look something like

```
user.add_role :moderator, Notes.where(account_id: params[:account_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a role to a particular instance as follows:

```
note = Notes.where(account_id: params[:account_id].first
user.add_role(:moderator, note)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a multi-tenant Rails app in production that uses Acts As Tenant and Rolify for a use case like you described. There are `User` accounts, which are independent from any tenant, each user can have multiple `Membership`s, thus be a member of multiple tenants.

Each users memberships can have individual roles. For the lower ranking roles, we needed to allow access to only certain instances that more privileged members can assign to them.

A good multi-tenant gem should take care of scoping all Rails models that you want to only one specific organization and prevent any member from organization A to access data from organization B. So there really should be no need to use something like `params[:account_id]` manually, when you want define a role scoped to a resource instance.